# Amazon MWS Products API returns 401 error "Access denied"

Tags: ios, objective-c, http, amazon-web-services, http-status-code-401

I'm hopelessly stuck on trying to call `Amazon MWS Products API`. Particularly I'm trying to request [this function](http://docs.developer.amazonservices.com/en_DE/products/Products_ListMatchingProducts.html)

It requires building a pretty complicated request with a signature:

```
POST /Products/2011-10-01 HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: x-www-form-urlencoded
Host: mws.amazonservices.com
User-Agent: <Your User Agent Header>

AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAEXAMPLEFWR4TJ7ZQ
&Action=ListMatchingProducts
&MWSAuthToken=amzn.mws.4ea38b7b-f563-7709-4bae-87aeaEXAMPLE
&MarketplaceId=ATVPDKIKX0DER
&Query=0439708184
&SellerId=A1IMEXAMPLEWRC
&SignatureMethod=HmacSHA256
&SignatureVersion=2
&Timestamp=2012-12-12T22%3A23%3A50Z
&Version=2011-10-01
&Signature=V%2BEXAMPLERT%2Baj%2Fxwqo7y3PIifMFHeqFlNYW0EXAMPLEA%3D
```

I build this query with the help of this [little library](https://github.com/m1entus/RWMAmazonProductAdvertisingManager):

So my final url string looks like this:

```
https://mws.amazonservices.com/Products/2011-10-01?AWSAccessKeyId=<MY_ACCESS_KEY>&Action=ListMatchingProducts&MarketplaceId=A1PA6795UKMFR9&Query=0439708184&SellerId=<SELLER_ID>&SignatureMethod=HmacSHA256&SignatureVersion=2&Timestamp=2016-04-19T16%3A50%3A13Z&Version=2011-10-01&Signature=mZt3OhM14gwLdsQ%2Bhxz5UFMzr7m2U36DvZ7RG3dcsTI%3D
```

And it seems that the url string is built correctly. I think so because if a parameter is missing or incorrect the API returns 400 error with explanation that this parameter is invalid. The same applies for the signature. If signature is incorrect the API returns error which clearly states that the signature is invalid. So, again, I think that the url must be ok. However the API returns 401 error and a html page which looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ErrorResponse xmlns="http://mws.amazonservices.com/schema/Products/2011-10-01">
<Error>
<Type>Sender</Type>
<Code>AccessDenied</Code>
<Message>Access denied</Message>
</Error>
<RequestID>7b12e3c8-7b1a-4b6e-b7ba-15ec8c4e0968</RequestID>
</ErrorResponse>
```

Access denied. And I have no idea why. I've spent several hours already trying to figure out what's wrong. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The reason for the problem was that I was calling American url `https://mws.amazonservices.com` instead of European one `https://mws-eu.amazonservices.com`. It would be really nice if Amazon response gave more context about the error than simply `Access denied`